# CSS transitions not executing at the same time

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I've created a super simple accordion where I use a `h3`/`p` setup and the `p`s initially have `max-height: 0` but if the `h3` has an `.open` class the `p` gets something like `max-height: 100px` (`h3.open + p {max-height: 100px}`).

Then I use a few lines of jQuery to add the `open` class to the clicked `h3`.

The problem I'm having is that when I click a heading it first slides out, and then like half a second later the other one slides back up. Why aren't the transitions executing at the exact same time?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2uhVY/

And here's all the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h3>Some question</h3>
    <p>Some answer</p>
    <h3>Some question</h3>
    <p>Some answer</p>
    <h3>Some question</h3>
    <p>Some answer</p>
    <h3>Some question</h3>
    <p>Some answer</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.accordion {

}

.accordion h3 {
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion p {
    margin: 20px 0;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 1s;
    transition: max-height 1s;
}

.accordion h3.open + p {
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

**JS (jQuery)**

```
$(function () {
    var h3s = $('.accordion h3');

    h3s.click(function () {
        h3s.removeClass('open');
        $(this).addClass('open');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `max-height` is transitioning from `100px` to `0`. Your elements aren’t that tall, so their heights don’t actually start to change until near the end of the transition.

Comment: Yep, that's why.. 1+ Here is a good demonstration using a height of `20px`: http://jsfiddle.net/Hz82p/

Comment: Oh was it that simple :P Do you have any suggestions for a solution that works better? I can't set the `max-height` too low because the amount of text in each paragraph is not fixed.

Comment: @powerbuoy: As much as I hate to say it… you’ll have to use jQuery for now. Sorry. =(

Comment: damn. too good. you saved me time since i would not have figured that out on my own!