# Run function after another is finished on accordion-like tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-callback

I am trying to do something like an accordion effect. When you click on a "tab" it should close the one that is already open and THEN open the one that was clicked.
But what is happening is that it is first opening the one clicked, and THEN closing the one that was already open.

You can see it here:
https://boguz.github.io/SWCanonTimeline/

I am using the following jQuery:

```
// DOCUMENT READY FUNCTION
$(document).ready(function () {

// CLICK ON STRIPE
$(".stripe").on("click", function() {

    closeStripe();

    openStripe( $(this) );

});

}); // end of document.ready


// CLOSE OPEN STRIPE
function closeStripe() {

    $(".open").removeClass("open");

}

// OPEN CLICKED STRIPE
function openStripe(stripe) {

    stripe.addClass("open");

}
```

I have tried using `$.when().done()` but didn't manage to make it work. I also tried making it a callback function but without success.

Comment: As there's no jquery animation commands (such as `.close()` or `.slideUp()`), it's safe to assume (given that it's not in the question) that you are using css transitions.  It's not easy to "queue" up css transitions as jquery doesn't know about them - you might like to look at using jquery (as per the question tags).

Comment: `.when().done()` is for ajax promises and has nothing to do with jquery animations (nor css transitions).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS transitions not executing at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341151/css-transitions-not-executing-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following Terry's advice and I used the `toggleSlide` function from jQuery to animate the tabs.

Here is the code I am using now:

```
// DOCUMENT READY FUNCTION
$(document).ready(function () {

    // on tab click
    $(".stripe").on("click", function() {

        // close all open tabs
        $(this).siblings().children(".content").slideUp();

        // open just clicked tab
        $(this).children(".content").slideToggle();

    });

}); // end of document.ready
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't the JavaScript. You trigger both animations at the same time, so they should happen simultaneously (and they do). But they are CSS transitions and they are for `max-height`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341151/css-transitions-not-executing-at-the-same-time) is pretty similar actually.

What happens is that you transition `max-height` from `1000px` down to `100px`, but your element is only about `700px` high, so you won't see anything for the first `300px`.

What you can do is wait for the `closeStripe()` animation to finish using a `setTimeout()`:

```
$(".stripe").on("click", function() {
    closeStripe();
    var duration = Number($(this).css('transition-duration').match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/)[0])*1000;
    setTimeout(function () {
        openStripe($(this));
    }, duration);
});
```

This gets the duration from the `transition-duration` property and converts it to a string (not well tested).

Answer (score 1):

The observed delay is due to the transition of the `max-height` property. The max-height of an open accordion is set to 1000px, while the closed one is set to 100px. That means that the browser will perform a transition from 100px to 1000px. When your open accordion does not have the actual content height of 1000px, the transition will be delayed as the browser is simply tweening the value from 1000px downwards, and the content will only collapse when the value tweened reaches, or is less than, the value of `max-height`.

An alternative solution would be a JS-based one, where you use `.slideUp(500)` and `.slideDown(500)` instead of CSS transitions. These jQuery functions will take into account the actual height of the accordion, instead of tweening the `max-height` attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".stripe").on("click", function() {
    closeStripe();
    openStripe($(this));
  });
});

// CLOSE OPEN STRIPE
function closeStripe() {
  $(".stripe").removeClass("open").find("div.content").slideUp(500);
}
// OPEN CLICKED STRIPE
function openStripe(stripe) {
  stripe.addClass("open").find("div.content").slideDown(500);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
}
body, html { width: 100vw; }
section.head {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #f4f2f2;
}
.menu {
  height: 80px;
  width: 260px;
  float: left;
}
h1.title {
  width: calc( 100vw - 520px );
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #666;
}
.social {
  width: 260px;
  height: 80px;
  float: right;
}
.stripe {
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.stripe[data-eventType="book"] { background-color: #F4D03F; }
.stripe[data-eventType="comic"] { background-color: #E67E22; }
.stripe[data-eventType="movie"] { background-color: #D64541; }
.stripe[data-eventType="tv"] { background-color: #C0392B; }
.stripe[data-eventType="game"] { background-color: #674172; }
.stripe:hover { border-color: #f4f2f2; }
.stripe.open:hover { border-color: transparent; }
.stripeTitle {
  font-size: 4em;
  color: white;
  line-height: 160px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.content {
  width: calc( 100vw - 100px );
  background-color: #f4f2f2;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content p {
  color: #666;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="head">
  <div class="menu"></div>
  <h1 class="title">Star Wars Canon Timeline</h1>
  <div class="social"></div>
</section>
<!-- end section.head -->
<section class="main">
  <div class="stripe" data-eventtype="movie">
    <h2 class="stripeTitle">32 bby</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>HERE WILL COME THE CONTENT</p>
    </div>
    <!-- end .content -->
  </div>
  <!-- end stripe -->
  <div class="stripe open" data-eventtype="comic">
    <h2 class="stripeTitle">29 bby</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>HERE WILL COME THE CONTENT</p>
    </div>
    <!-- end .content -->
  </div>
  <!-- end stripe -->
  <div class="stripe" data-eventtype="movie">
    <h2 class="stripeTitle">22 bby</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>HERE WILL COME THE CONTENT</p>
    </div>
    <!-- end .content -->
  </div>
  <!-- end stripe -->
  <div class="stripe" data-eventtype="movie">
    <h2 class="stripeTitle">22 bby</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>HERE WILL COME THE CONTENT</p>
    </div>
    <!-- end .content -->
  </div>
  <!-- end stripe -->
  <div class="stripe" data-eventtype="tv">
    <h2 class="stripeTitle">22 - 20 bby</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>HERE WILL COME THE CONTENT</p>
    </div>
    <!-- end .content -->
  </div>
  <!-- end stripe -->
  <div class="stripe" data-eventtype="comic">
    <h2 class="stripeTitle">20 bby</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>HERE WILL COME THE CONTENT</p>
    </div>
    <!-- end .content -->
  </div>
  <!-- end stripe -->
</section>
<!-- end section.main -->
```

Comment: yes, using the slideUp seems like a be a good way to do it. Thanks!